# pgfmath: Integers without zeros, non-integers with zerofill (and fixed)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, pgfmath, number

[image]

**I want:** 
· integers without zeros, e.g. -2 ---> -2 (not -2.0000) 
· non-integers with zerofill, 
e.g. 1.23 ---> 1.2300 
e.g. 1.2345 --> 1.2345

**Hints:** 
· A `pgfmath`-solution would be nice (in the difference to siunitx etc.). 
· And I need that in a `pgfplotstable`, but I do not know whether this is a pgfplotstable-specific problem.

What do I have to set?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}
\section{Actual}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
fixed relative,
zerofill,  precision=4,  % no effect
]{
0, 1,  -2,  1.23,  1.2345
}

\section{Target}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{
0, 1,  -2,  1.2300,  1.2345
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: -2 should stay -2 not 2.0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set key `/pgfplots/table/@cell content` from hook `/pgfplots/table/assign cell content` in order to define custom output markup for each cell. The argument of `assign cell content` is the unformatted data read from the input table. `\pgfmathifisint` allows one to run conditional code that depends on whether said data represents an integer.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  every column/.style={
    assign cell content/.code={%
      \pgfmathifisint{##1}
        {\def\myOptions{}}%
        {\def\myOptions{fixed, zerofill, precision=4}}%
      \expandafter\pgfmathprintnumberto\expandafter[\myOptions]
        {\pgfretval}{\myFormattedValue}%
      \pgfplotstableset{@cell content/.expand once=\myFormattedValue}%
    },
  }]{
0, 1,  -2,  1.23,  1.2345
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The hook `/pgfplots/table/assign cell content` is run inside a TeX group, therefore there is no need to manually clean up macros `\myOptions` and `\myFormattedValue` afterwards: this is automatic.

The following is equivalent and shorter, but has a bit more redundancy:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  every column/.style={
    assign cell content/.code={%
      \pgfmathifisint{##1}
        {\pgfmathprintnumberto{\pgfretval}{\myFormattedValue}}
        {\pgfmathprintnumberto[fixed, zerofill, precision=4]
           {\pgfretval}{\myFormattedValue}}%
      \pgfplotstableset{@cell content/.expand once=\myFormattedValue}%
    },
  }]{
0, 1,  -2,  1.23,  1.2345
}

\end{document}
```

Also possible, putting all the logic inside each `@cell content` (which might use a bit more memory, perhaps?):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=comma}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  every column/.style={
    assign cell content/.style={
      @cell content={%
        \pgfmathifisint{##1}
          {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfretval}}
          {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, zerofill, precision=4]{\pgfretval}}%
      },
    },
  }]{
0, 1,  -2,  1.23,  1.2345
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used at mine:   `every column/.style={postproc cell content/.style={
@cell content=\pgfmathifisint{##1}
        {\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{##1}}  
        {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,  fixed zerofill,  precision=5]{##1}}  
}},`  seems a tick easier. ;)

Comment: Yes, this is possible but short-circuits the `assign cell content` filter. Indeed, if you look at the value of `@cell content` from within `postproc cell content`, you'll see it is already formatted output with `$` signs around (for numerical cells, not `string type`, etc.). Therefore, I prefer respecting all stages of the filtering, and thus testing numerical values before they get formatted.

Comment: I added a variant in this spirit (marginally shorter but more redundant code-wise), still using `assign cell content`.